# IndexError: list index out of range only for loops?

Tags: python, loops, file, range, txt

I've been trying to make my program read a different line from a file each time the loop is completed. This works the first time but once the first loop is completed I am presented with **IndexError: list index out of range**.  How can I fix this?

The file titled **s is 18239** lines long and the file titled **sp is 1000** lines long.

```
from itertools import count
import time
import webbrowser
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller
import random
import string  
import secrets 



number = random.randint(0,18238)
number2 = random.randint(0,18238)
kb = Controller()
cout = 0
f = open('D:\Scripts\sp.txt', 'r')
fi = open('D:\Scripts\s.txt', 'r')
fil = open('D:\Scripts\s.txt', 'r')
while cout < 1000:
    linecount = random.randint(0,999)
    line = f.readlines()[linecount]
    lines = line.split()
    email = lines[0]
    password= lines[1]
    name = fi.readlines()[number]
    name2 = fil.readlines()[number2]
    firstname = name.rstrip("\n")
    lastname = name2.rstrip("\n")
```

Comment: Where do you increment count ?

Comment: Which specific line of code throws the error?  What are the exact values used when the error occurs?

Comment: `linecount` has the wrong name. That is a random number and is not a linecount. Next, you call `f.readlines()` in a loop. After the first time, all lines are already read. What do you expect to happen during the second loop? There's nothing more to read. `lines` has the wrong name, again. It is not multiple lines. If `readlines()` returns an array of lines, `readlines()[linecount]` will already give you a single line. Basically: you do not want to read the full file `f` a thousand times. Just do it once, then work with the data you have.

Comment: @David line = f.readlines()[linecount] and then i also assume if it got to it name = fi.readlines()[number] and name2 = fil.readlines()[number2]

Comment: @CharlesMarcucci it is incremented later this just is the only bit of code not working

Comment: @ThomasWeller should switch readlines for readline

Comment: `readline()` (without s) will not work either, as long as you want to access it with an index of `linecount` (or it will give you a single character, but likely it's index out of range)

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes your right i tried readline and and stated linecount after and it was out of range, is there a possible way of reading a specific line from a file one at a time?

Comment: i could always use enumerate

Comment: First, check what the value of `line` is each time through the loop, then see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now after some consideration I look at what was this issue, turns out python has issues re-reading files and so you have to put the readlines() outside the loop I ended up using read()

Here's what I did to fix the issue
this version of the code worked perfectly with no issues (no re-reading files guys python will cry), this version also keeps the purpose of the code (to read a specific random line each loop)

```
import time
import webbrowser
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller
import random
import string  
import secrets 




kb = Controller()
cout = 0
f = open('D:\Scripts\sp.txt', 'r')
fi = open('D:\Scripts\s.txt', 'r')
fil = open('D:\Scripts\s.txt', 'r')
lines = f.read().split("\n")   #outside the main loop to avoid index range error#
name = fi.read().split("\n")   #outside the main loop to avoid index range error#
while cout < 1000:
    linez = lines[random.randint(0,999)] # and then determine the line inside the loop#
    line = linez.split()
    email = line[0]
    password= line[1]
    names = name[random.randint(0,18238)] # and then determine the line inside the loop#
    namez = name[random.randint(0,18238)] # and then determine the line inside the loop#
    firstname = names.rstrip("\n")
    lastname = namez.rstrip("\n")
```